# Is there a way to programmatically check the connectivity to SAP?

Tags: mulesoft, jco

As a mulesoft developer, I want to **programmatically** check the connectivity to a SAP system, as it is done in AnypointStudio GUI by clicking the button "Test Connection".

[image: Hitting the Test Connection Button]

The Mulesoft connector used is the SAP JCO Connector.

Thank you

Below is my sap config global configuration:

```
<sap:sap-config name="SAP_CONFIG" doc:name="SAP Config" doc:id="c696ca6a-4ca6-4840-87ba-299b83f62179" >
        <sap:simple-connection-provider-connection username="${app.sap.hana.jcoUser}" password="${app.sap.hana.jcoPassword}" systemNumber="${app.sap.hana.jcoSysNr}" client="${app.sap.hana.jcoClient}"  language="${app.sap.hana.jcoLang}" >
            <reconnection>
                <reconnect-forever />
            </reconnection>
            <sap:message-server host="${app.sap.hana.jcoMsHost}" systemId="${app.sap.hana.jcoMsSysId}" group="${app.sap.hana.jcoMsGrpName}"/>
        <sap:extended-properties >
                <sap:extended-property key="jco.server.max_startup_delay" value="300" />
            </sap:extended-properties>
        </sap:simple-connection-provider-connection>
        <expiration-policy maxIdleTime="1" timeUnit="HOURS" />
    </sap:sap-config>
```

Below is the flow that listens SAP IDOCs;
[image]

When the connection is lost, it does not automatically reconnect.

Comment: Are you running Anypoint Studio in production to check connectivity? I don't think so. Please state the issue that you are really trying to resolve, symptoms, errors and versions used.

Comment: Hello @aled, and thank you. You're right, AnypointStudio is not meant to be run in prod.
The reason I am showing it here is to highlight the "Test Connection" button, and wanted to know which function was behind that button.  Mule-runtime-version: 4.4

Comment: You said it does not automatically reconnect? so does it get connected again then? do it get connected after a restart?

Comment: Hello @HarshankBansal; thank you. Yes it does reconnect after a restart.

Comment: Hello and thank you all for your support. 
The reconnection issue has been fixed by adding the following 2 elements in the sap/jco connector configuration:  reconnection, expiration-policy                                                                   
 <sap:sap-config name="SAP_HANA" 
  <sap:simple-connection-provider-connection 
   <reconnection>
    <reconnect-forever frequency="5000"/>
   </reconnection>
   <sap:message-server ......  
  </sap:simple-connection-provider-connection>
  <expiration-policy maxIdleTime="2" timeUnit="MINUTES" />
 </sap:sap-config>

Comment: Can you post it as an answer and accept it too. It will be helpful for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and thank you all for your support.

**The reconnection issue has been fixed** by adding the following 2 elements in the sap/jco connector configuration:

reconnection, expiration-policy

```
<sap:sap-config name="SAP_HANA" <sap:simple-connection-provider-connection <reconnection> <reconnect-forever frequency="5000"/> </reconnection> <sap:message-server ...... </sap:simple-connection-provider-connection> <expiration-policy maxIdleTime="2" timeUnit="MINUTES" /> </sap:sap-config>
```

[Setting the expiration-policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqTiP.png)

[Setting the reconnection option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCTHb.png)